App crashing when login in to MainActivity in Android Studio Java
I am using Firebase as my database for my app which is a chatting app. My app crashes whenever I try to log in or sign up for my app's main activity the app crashes automatically.
MainActivity.java
package com.vortexv.vconnect;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.firebase.Firebase;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseAuth auth;
    RecyclerView mainUserRecyclerView;
    UserAdapter adapter;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    ArrayList<Users> usersArrayList;

    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference().child("user");
        usersArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        mainUserRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.mainUserRecyclerView);
        mainUserRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new UserAdapter(MainActivity.this, usersArrayList);
        mainUserRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    Users users = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
                    usersArrayList.add(users);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });




        if (auth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}

Users.java
package com.vortexv.vconnect;

public class Users {
    String profilepic,mail,userName,password,userID,lastMessage,status;

    public Users(String id, String namee, String emaill, String password, String imageuri, String status){
        this.userID = id;
        this.userName = namee;
        this.mail = emaill;
        this.password = password;
        this.profilepic = imageuri;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getProfilepic() {
        return profilepic;
    }

    public void setProfilepic(String profilepic) {
        this.profilepic = profilepic;
    }

    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }

    public void setMail(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(String userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getLastMessage() {
        return lastMessage;
    }

    public void setLastMessage(String lastMessage) {
        this.lastMessage = lastMessage;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}

MainActivity.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_bg"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_24sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_semibold"
            android:text="Vortex Connect"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logout_img"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_50sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/baseline_logout_24" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/mainUserRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="369dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolBar"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="159dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="114dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_32sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_32sdp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_72sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="270dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_32sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/camera_white_icon" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_32sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_32sdp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_138sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="193dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_32sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/chats_white_icon" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_32sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_32sdp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_200sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="113dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_32sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/settings_white_icon" />
</RelativeLayout>

Stack Trace
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                                 Process: com.vortexv.vconnect, PID: 28436
                                                                                                    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class com.vortexv.vconnect.Users does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped.
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:578)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:571)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:433)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:232)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(CustomClassMapper.java:80)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:202)
                                                                                                        at com.vortexv.vconnect.MainActivity$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:56)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:211)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:300)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8348)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:582)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1028)

Logs provided if its helped:
link - cuz its showing spam on posting page
I am watching a tutorial on youtube to make this app. Here is the link : Click here `
My app is crashing on my main Activity which is my chat home screen.
I have tired to rewrite the code but my problem is not solving. Please help!!

Please don't post screenshots of your error message, stack trace, code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? and Formatting text and code

If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please respond using @AlexMamo

@AlexMamo thank you sir for replying. I am still learning android studio. I have updated my question with Stack Trace you can check or if something is wrong you can guide.

@AlexMamo sir updated the question with stack trace.

You're getting the following error:

com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class com.vortexv.vconnect.Users does not define a no-argument constructor.

Because your Users class does not contain the no-argument constructor.
In Java, when a class has no constructors, there is a default no-argument constructor automatically added by the compiler. The moment you define any constructor in the class, the default no-argument constructor goes away.
You have defined in your class a constructor with 6 arguments. So as long as this constructor is present in the class, the no-argument constructor doesn't exist, so you have to create it:
public class Users {
    String profilepic,mail,userName,password,userID,lastMessage,status;

    public Users() {} //

    public Users(String id, String namee, String emaill, String password, String imageuri, String status){
        this.userID = id;
        this.userName = namee;
        this.mail = emaill;
        this.password = password;
        this.profilepic = imageuri;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getProfilepic() {
        return profilepic;
    }

    public void setProfilepic(String profilepic) {
        this.profilepic = profilepic;
    }

    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }

    public void setMail(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(String userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getLastMessage() {
        return lastMessage;
    }

    public void setLastMessage(String lastMessage) {
        this.lastMessage = lastMessage;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}

When the Firebase Realtime Database SDK deserializes objects from the database, it requires that any objects in use, to have this constructor, so it can use it to instantiate the object.
If you don't have the public no-arg constructor, the SDK doesn't really know how to create an instance of it. So it is mandatory to have it.

thank you so much sir that small mistake took my one week. Thanks a lot
